# T-test: Difference in Mean: which increased faster in a given time period?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

Is it possible to do hypothesis testing on which mean increased faster?
For example, samples are
A (1994) - 1, 2, 3
A (2014) - 2, 4, 6
B (1994) - 1, 2, 4
B (2014( - 2, 4, 16

Obviously the mean of A has increased faster in from 2014 to 2015 than the mean of B has, but is there a viable hypothesis testing that I can use?  I figured that a regular difference in mean hypothesis testing would not work as the variance would be of all data points of A or B instead of each one's yearly variance (if what I am saying makes any sense).  Please help thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is not your actual data, but you could use a t-test to compare the change (X2014-X1995) or the ratio (X2014/X1995) of the scores between groups A and B. The residuals can then be evaluated for normality and equality of variance. If the residuals aren't distributed as hoped you could try transforming either of the above options (eg sqrt) and running it again.